# SQL Injection Technique For Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

I've been trying to ensure my code isn't susceptible to the infamous *SQL Injection Attack*.  The question involves the *Query String*, the legacy code I'm managing has instances of inline SQL which applies:

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM [Order] 
   WHERE ([Id]=" + Request.QueryString[@"oid"] + ");";
```

Obviously that is bad, it will take the attack.  My question is this enough?

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", Request.QueryString[@"oid"]);
```

So now the query has a parameter, which is being passed a value.  I know it has some form of encoding.  However, will that be enough as any malicious attacker could exploit that query string?  So should I do `Encode` on the query string?  That way it will encode it safely to avoid being exploited any further?

Some clarification on the matter would be helpful.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is this enough?

No - you also need to change your query to

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM [Order] 
   WHERE ([Id]=@OrderId);";
```

> I know it has some form of encoding

No, it uses the actual value, but *it does not inject it into the SQL statement*.  It treats it as a literal string, so there's no way to include punctuation or malicious code that will get interpreted as SQL.

**EDIT**

I may have misunderstood - you may need to URL-decode the value if it included URL-encoded characters (`%20`, `&amp;`, etc. ), but no encoding (or decoding) is necessary to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I know the query has to be changed to use that parameter, should of added that to the question, sorry.  So `Parameters.AddWithValue` should be enough because of how it converts?

Comment: @Greg It doesn't convert.  It will insert the string value as-is.  You do not need to worry about encoding or escaping characters.